# Is there a way to access hard drives while computer sleeps?

Tags: computer-networks, power-consumption

Is there any way at all possible or possible with hardware (aside from a NAS) to access hard drives while the computer is in a low power mode such as sleep (aside from WOL)?

For example, can I log into a networked drive located on the computer and spin it up to access data without the computer coming out of low power mode?

Comment: shouldn't this question belong to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  It all depends on the architecture of the machine.  For instance, if there is a co-processor that is awake and responds to the network requests by accessing the hard drive, that would be one way to accomplish it.

If you're asking about a specific product or technology, that is off-topic here.  But conceptually, you can certainly build a computer that has this capability.  Whether any individual computer does have that capability is a question about that specific product or technology.